# Dynamically loading and autoplaying HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, html5-video, autoload

I am trying to grab a video URL from `data-src` and add it to `src` for my video. I have that much working when I snoop the page code but the video isn't showing up on the page and playing. I'm using jQuery since I have a few other bits of code using it to run some functionality.

**Markup:**

```
<video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" poster="/assets/video/bg-ss-vid.jpg">
    <source type="video/mp4" data-src="/assets/video/bg-ss-vid.mp4">
</video>
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    $("#site-hero video").each(function () {
        $('source', $(this)).attr("src", $('source', $(this)).data('src'));
        $('source', $(this)).removeAttr('data-src');
    });
});
```

How do I get it to show up / play the video after the `src` has been loaded?

Comment: Have you tried `$('#site-hero video').get(0).play()`?

Comment: I did but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Well, have you debugged it to see why it didn't work?

Comment: @doutriforce all I see is. `<source> element has no “src” attribute. Media resource load failed.  supersplash
All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused.` Which I assume has to do with it not initially having a `src`.

Comment: Aren't you trying to `.play()` _after_ you have set the `src` though?

Comment: See my answer below. I'm not getting the "has no src" error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.play()` *after* adding it's `src`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  "use strict";

  $("video").each(function() {
    var $source = $(this).find('source');
    var src = $source.attr('data-src');
    
    $source.removeAttr('data-src');
    $source.attr('src', src);
    $source.detach().appendTo($(this))
    
    $(this).get(0).play();
  });
});
```

```css
video {
  width: 420px;
  height: 230px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video loop="loop" poster="http://placehold.it/420x230">
    <source type="video/mp4" data-src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Yeah this code still isn't working for me. Is it working for you? I made a JSFiddle of it https://jsfiddle.net/xoq2hLa2/1/

Comment: Yes. Right here on the snippet. It autoplays and also loops.

Comment: Interestingly enough it's working in Safari but not Firefox or Chrome. I tried on a few computers.

Comment: @tylorreimer, i have updated the answer. Try again, please.

Comment: Thanks @doutriforce the updated solution is working great. Thank you!